# Python: How can one open Thread handle multiple api requests?

Tags: python, multithreading, api, request

I am using Flask-restx and Spacy NER model.

I have an api that has to receive a text and an Id No., predict a label and return the same using a spacy nlp model. This nlp model is specific to a particular Id number.

Example: For Id '1', nlp model 'a' is to be loaded and used for prediction; for Id '2', nlp model 'b' is to be used, etc.

I want to know if it is possible that I can keep open Threads for particular Ids which have preloaded the specific nlp model and when a request is sent, according to the id number, that particular Thread which is open can process the data and return a value quick.

Example:
The api has received a request that a new nlp model 'x' has been created for id '5' and is going to be used, so a new Thread is opened with a loaded model 'x' and all requests that have id number '5' are processed by this Thread only.

The aim is that there is a preloaded model present, so when a request is sent, it can be processed and value returned in a few seconds. Loading the spacy model takes around 30 seconds which cannot be done every time a request is sent as there will be a timeout.

Can this be done or is there any other way it can be done?

Comment: Yes it can be done but is there a specific reason why each NLP model needs its own *Thread*? If they can be just Python objects which load the data set when initialized, then you can simply instantiate a global set of them at startup, insert them into a dict for name->obj mapping and use them from the request handlers. If they are not thread-safe you have to syncronize with `Lock` objects.

Comment: There will be new models created which would make me unable to load them during startup. When a new Id is made, a database table will tell me which model is to be used for that id which then needs to be loaded. The only problem is that, with every request, I cannot load the specific model in real-time.

Comment: Ok sounds like you don't really need more Threads, explaining how to do it in my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you just rely on the Flask threading model and wrap the NLP models into objects which implement lazy loading of the model (only when it is needed) and a separate factory function which creates and caches these objects. Add a threading.Lock to make sure only one Flask thread is in the NLP parser at a time.

Example code:

```
from threading import Lock

MODELS = {}

class NlpModel():
    _model = None
    _lock = Lock()

    def __init__(self, model_id):
        self._id = model_id

    @property
    def model(self):
        if self._model is None:
            self._model = slow_load_model_with_something(self._id)
        return self._model

    def parse(self, data):
        with self._lock:
            # only one thread will be in here at a time
            return self.model.do_your_thing(data)


def get_model(model_id):
  model = MODELS.get(model_id, None)
  if not model:
    model = NlpModel(model_id)
    MODELS[model_id] = model
  return model

# Example Flask route
@app.route('/parse/<model_id>')
def parse_model(model_id):
    model = get_model(model_id)
    model.parse(data_from_somewhere)
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this solution. I incorporated it in my code and it works great! I am new to this field and was stuck on this situation for some time, not knowing how to solve the problem. Thank you again!